# update the data in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm trying to update some fields from firebase but I'm getting an error at doc_ref.docs.update({'tripname': 'Mumbai'}); stating update is defined. I'm working on flutter first time and not sure where I,m doing wrong.

```
 var doc_ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("tripdetails")
                        .doc(user?.uid)
                        .collection("trips")
                        .get();

                    doc_ref.docs.forEach((result) {
                      print(result.id);
                      doc_ref.docs.update({'tripname': 'Mumbai'});
                    });
```

Comment: print(result.id); its lists all the documents but I want to update one a document at a time.. I'm not sure how to do it. Please help me

Comment: use a loop for result list if you say its a list in the forEach function